# How do i know if the interior of a polygon lies to the right or to the left of a vertex?

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, computational-geometry

I am trying to make monotone a polygon so i can triangulate it, but i am having a problem with the regular vertex (A vertex with one neighbor above it, one neighbor below it:
[image]

The algorithm for handle regular vertex is confusing me because i don't know whether the polygon lies to the right or the left:
[image]

The algorithm is in the book Computational Geometry Algorithms and Applications Third Edition

Comment: Is 'regular vertex' the most left or the most right vertex of polygon?

Comment: Both. http://i.stack.imgur.com/dtyNJ.png

Comment: OK, I inserted picture links in your question.

Comment: Did you ever solve it? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

First you calculate the signed aera of the entire polygon. The sign of the aera will tell you if the winding order of the vertices of the polygon are clockwise or counter-clockwise.

You'll only have to do this once, and it's a cheap operation.

Then to find out if you have a left- or right regular vertex you only have to take a look at the indices of the previous and next vertex. There are either ascending or decending.

A little table will now tell you if you're on the left or right side:

```
Counter-Clockwise Polygon:
--------------------------
Ascending order: Regular vertex is on the left of the polygon
Descending order: Regular vertex is on the right of the polygon


Clockwise Polygon:
--------------------------
Ascending order: Regular vertex is on the right of the polygon
Descending order: Regular vertex is on the left of the polygon
```

So no need to do any expensive ray intersections or point-in-polygon tests.

I've implemented that algorithm several years ago, and it was a big help to analyze the winding order of the polygon at the start and - if counter-clockwise - reverse the winding order before doing any further processing.

This removes a lot of cases where the control-flow depend on the winding order. You'll end up with much cleaner and easier to follow code that way.

Comment: Sounds easier than the point in polygon, but i didn't understand it. What you mean by ascending/descending order? Are you talking about the indices order?

Comment: @HansBlanco  Yes, exactly, the indices. If you draw a polygon clockwise and observer the indices you'll see how easy it is to find the left and right side. Just be sure you'll deal with the wrap-around case.

Comment: Sorry, i still don't get it. For example in the image the polygon is counterclockwise.  v2 is a right regular vertex and the indices of the previous and next vertex are 1 and 3. v10 is a left regular vertex and the indices of the previous and next vertex are 9 and 11. How does that help to know the kind of vertex?

Comment: @HansBlanco forgot to mention: Count from top to bottom and the order of the neighbour vertices tells you which side the regular vertex is on. You should have a lexicographical ordering of the vertices anyway, so looking this up is cheap.

Comment: @HansBlanco Fine. Note that you don't do any computations with the vertex coordinates, so the solution is numerical stable as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make a ray from regular point to the right. Find if it intersects with edges and get number of these intersections. If it is odd, polygon lies to the right.

This approach is close to **Point in polygon** algorithm {[example, discussing non-trivial cases](http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/~wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html)}

Probably, in book algorithm you have got this information with another means. For example, you might know that walk order is clockwise or anti-clockwise.